# how can i replace an image (inside a div) through jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, image

I am trying to click on an image and change it to another image through jquery.

When i step through the below code, on the serverside, the controller action fires and on the client side, i can see the correct html return in firebug watch window but the image doesn't change at all.  any idea why this div is not updating?

**original div:**

```
<div class="inlineDiv" toggle="off" id="22"><img src="../../images/vote-favorite-off1.png" border="0"></div>
```

**jquery code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.inlineDiv').live('click', function() {

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var toggle = $(this).attr("toggle");

        var url = '/Tracker/Update?id=' + id + '&toggle=' + toggle;

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $(this).html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**controller action:**

```
  public ActionResult Update(int id, string toggle)
  {
       if (toggle == "off")
        {
            return Content("<img src='../../images/vote-favorite-on1.png' border=0'>");
        }
        return Content("<img src='../../images/vote-favorite-off1.png' border=0'>");
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe the `this` in the get is referring to the get's function.

easier:

```
$(this).load(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` isn't referring to the correct object at this point. Try assigning the object to a variable first, or just say `$('div.inlineDiv').html(data)`

```
var objDiv=$(this);
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        objDiv.html(data);
    });
```

another method would be `$('div.inlineDiv img').attr('src',returnedPath);`
but you'd have to update the controller action to return just the src path.

or as said below `$('div.inlineDiv').load(URL);`