# how to change base64 by mouse scroll asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a base64 variable that i use to display an image

```
 public ActionResult openNextImage(){

       string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imagebyte);
       string imageDataURL =string.Format("data:image/png;base64{0}",base64);
       ViewBag.ImageData = imageDataURL;
       return view();
  }
```

and i am trying to change this image when the user scroll/click on the image but i cant get it working. this is my view code

```
   <a href="@Url.Action("openNextImage", "MedicalImagesController")">                        

        <img src="@ViewBag.ImageData" width="1000" height=" 600" />

    </a>
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: If I undertand you correct you need to do it with js ajax call. You should search [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676134/how-can-i-replace-an-image-inside-a-div-through-jquery-and-ajax).

Comment: I intend to do it purely in C# if its possible

Comment: It is possible only if you want to reaload whole page, but i suppose you want to realod only part of it - then you should use js.